# What is the correct character for splitting a string on line breaks in Vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, string-manipulation

Consider the following text file.

```
line1f line1n
line2
```

Suppose I visual select this, yank it into register a, and then pass it to the following vimscript function:

```
function TestSplit(block)
 for x in split(a:block, "\0")
    echom x
    echom "hi"
 endfor
 return 0
endfunction
```

The output will be

```
line1f
hi
line1n
hi
line2
hi
```

What can I replace `\0` with to get the following output?

```
line1f line1n
hi
line2
hi
```

That is, I want to split on a logical newline for Vim. Note that I also tried `\r` and got this output.

```
line1f line1n^@line2
hi
```

Comment: use "\n" as split character (in double quotes)